# NoSQL Injection? (PHP->phpcassa->Cassandra)

Tags: nosql, cassandra, validation, code-injection

Anyone familiar enough with the Cassandra engine (via PHP using phpcassa lib) to know offhand whether there's a corollary to the sql-injection attack vector?  If so, has anyone taken a stab at establishing best practices to thwart them?  If not, would anyone like to ; )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The Thrift layer used by phpcassa is an rpc framework, not based on string parsing.

Comment: RPC approaches that don't strongly separate envelope and content (such as SOAP) may still be vulnerable to injection-type attacks. AFAIK, Thrift separates the two, so is safer - and the use of libraries such as phpcassa rather than raw sending makes things safer still. Which is a roundabout way of agreeing with jbellis.

Answer (score 11):

An update - Cassandra v0.8 introduced [CQL](http://crlog.info/2011/03/29/cassandra-query-language-aka-cql-syntax/), which might have brought with it the possibility of injection attacks. However:

[Prepared statements](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2475) were then introduced in Cassandra v1.1.0, which help to prevent such attacks.

Furthermore,  see [this posting](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg14907.html) which explains features of CQL that make it resistant to injection, including:

- each CQL query must contain exactly one statement
- as a rule of thumb, there are also no statement types that contain
  other statements, which would be another common vector for an
  injection.