# Is Datastax Java Driver vulnerable to injection attack?

Tags: java, cassandra, code-injection, cql, datastax-java-driver

Is DataStax Java Driver vulnerable to CQL injection attack if plain text CQL is used? Would using QueryBuilder help?

Comment: If it were, I think the developers would regard it as a bug in the driver and fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Security be available everywhere now via prepared statements:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2475

See also

[NoSQL Injection? (PHP->phpcassa->Cassandra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998838/nosql-injection-php-phpcassa-cassandra)

And
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201107.mbox/%3C1309630640.4e0f60b01d222@itchen.qinetiq.com%3E
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/CQL-injection-is-it-even-possible-td4976463.html

Comment: Excellant answer... but sadly not accepted. New docs on preventing sql  (cql?) injection: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/index.html#java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientBoundStatements_t.html